# Domain only responding to certain locations?

Tags: centos, domain, website

I have a client who's been having problems with his site.

The server doesn't seem to want to load hes site in certain countries, though other sites are fine. But this site [link removed] only seems to load in the US and Canada.

In Europe, the UK, Asia etc, the site seems to be blocked (been like this for a week now). I've looked over the server and it seems fine.  Other sites work fine, and the NS are set up properly, pointing to my main server, at http://puu.sh/MIGF

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Well, from what I can see, that's not actually the case.

There are a number of monitoring services and tools you can use to check the accessibility of a website from locations spread all over the world, and I guess I may as well give credit to the two free ones I ran against your domain really quickly.  (As with most places offering these quick, free tools, they also have more in depth tools and monitoring services for sale.)

[Uptrends](http://www.uptrends.com/aspx/free-website-server-network-monitoring-tool.aspx)

[Zoho's Site24x7](http://www.site24x7.com/check-website-availability.html)

Your site was accessible from all locations, with both tools, so I'm not sure what the problem (if anything) actually is here.  For next time, you should probably find a similar tool you like and use it before jumping to the conclusion that your site's not working outside North America.

Answer (score 1):

Your site may be blocked because its IP address was flagged by various online services as containing malware. When I tried to access the site, for instance, Malwarebytes came up and stopped it from being loaded.

Google doesn't have your site flagged for malware, though.

Looking at my Malwarebytes logs, it specifically matched on the IP address. That makes me think that your site is on shared web hosting, and likely some other site on that same IP address *is* distributing malware.